# How to reassign Workspace Switcher keyboard shortcut?

Tags: workspace-switcher

By default, to display the Workspace Switcher Overview I press super + s. But I would like it to occur when pressing F4. I do not see this option in Compiz > Window or Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Where else could I edit this from, including the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be many solutions.

The one I chose that worked was to install CompizConfig Settings Manager, search for "Expo", then the first option on the right allows you to customize the key.